# Распространение и использование тем для Debian Linux

Tags: linux, debian, gtk, themes

Поясните, пожалуйста, почему такой хаос в структуре тем на https://www.gnome-look.org? Захотел просто поставить тему (Debian 8, Mate) и столкнулся с проблемами.

Часть тем распространяется как `.deb` пакеты, что значительно упрощает работу с ними.

Другие темы распространяются с файлом `.theme`, что позволяет просто переместить каталог темы в `~/.themes/` и использовать ее. Однако такой способ дает не всегда работоспособную тему. Пример - [ambient-mate](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1170478/)

```
Ambiant-MATE
├── gtk-2.0
├── gtk-3.0
├── index.theme
├── metacity-1
└── unity
```

Другие используют структуру с файлом `gtkrc`. Пример - [material-sweet](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1151533/)

```
material-sweet-theme
├── gtk-2.0
│   ├── Arrows
│   ├── Buttons
│   ├── Check-Radio
│   ├── Combo
│   ├── Frame-Gap
│   ├── gtkrc
│   ├── Handles
│   ├── Lines
│   ├── ListHeaders
│   ├── Menu-Menubar
│   ├── Others
│   ├── Panel
│   ├── ProgressBar
│   ├── Scale
│   ├── Scrollbars
│   ├── Shadows
│   ├── Spin
│   ├── styles
│   ├── Tabs
│   └── Toolbar
└── xfce-notify-4.0
    └── gtkrc
```

Некоторые - вообще непонятный вид, с которым я не разобрался даже после `readme`. Пример - [hedera](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1166382/)

```
Hedera-master/
├── COPYING
├── debian
│   ├── changelog
│   ├── compat
│   ...
│   └── source
├── LICENSE
├── MANUAL
│   ├── Chromium
│   ...
│   ├── readme.md
│   └── WINE
├── readme.md
├── rpm
│   └── buildrpm.sh
└── THEME
    ├── albert
    ├── backgrounds
    ├── color-schemes
    ...
    ├── wallpapers
    ├── xfce4
    └── yakuake
```

Почему нет единообразия? И как использовать тему, например, из второго примера?

Аналогичные проблемы с иконками и шрифтами.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что каждая тема создается для одного или нескольких окружений рабочего стола (Gnome, XFCE и т.д.). В каждом окружении свои правила для тем, и в разных оболочках темы могут отображаться по-разному. Чтобы использовать тему, которая отображается криво, можно сменить окружение рабочего стола.

Comment: да, но ресурс посвящен темам gnome и других оболочек не упоминается.

Comment: Все-таки, бавают разные версии оболочек Gnome, например, Gnome Shell, Gnome 2 и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

#### Как копировать темы между различными дистрибутивами Linux

1. Скачиваем образ `Live CD/USB` понравившегося дистрибутива и запускаем его на виртуальной машине.
2. Внутри находим папки `/usr/share/icons/` и `/usr/share/themes/`. Копируем их содержимое на свою рабочую систему.

*Важно:* если на рабочей системе используется *GNOME*, тогда скачиваем образ с ним же - если *XFCE*, тогда, соответственно, *XFCE* - они не всегда совместимы, или вообще несовместимы. Также надо учитывать, что различные системы имеют свои особенности - одна и та же тема может выглядеть по-разному в `CentOS` и в `Debian`, даже если установлен один и тот же *DE*.

Такой способ лучше, т. к. в полноценных дистрибутивах полноценные темы. И даже если они будут выглядеть не совсем так, как в оригинале - можно будет подпилить самому. Результаты такого подпиливания можно найти в интернетах на подобных описанному в вопросе сайтах.

---

По поводу авторских прав: [Is it legal to copy themes between different linux distros?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/610977/339704)

> В большинстве случаев проблем быть не должно; исключения могут составлять темы с *брендингом* (но это непроверенная информация).